# VBScript to open, run and close Tor browser

Tags: vbscript, tor

Please edit this VBScript to open, run and close Tor browser:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Exec("""C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\Tor.exe""/http://www.google.com")
Set objShell = Nothing
WScript.Sleep 20000
Set objShell = objshell.Exec("taskkill /fi ""imagename eq Tor.exe""")
```

It opens and runs, but doesn't close.

Comment: I would try `objShell.Quit` instead of setting `objShell` again after your `WScript.Sleep 20000` and move setting it to Nothing to the very end.

Comment: For **objShell.Quit** I get the message that the object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Then I'd try `objShell.Terminate`.

Comment: I tried with **objShell.Terminate("""C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\Tor.exe""/http://www.google.com")** and **objShell.Terminate** but had the same error message. Do you see anything wrong with these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try something like this :

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "Taskkill /F /IM Tor.exe",0,True
```